# MVC .net core : response type always json not xml with ICollection

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I use this contribution for return json or xml depending "Accept" header.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/formatting

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlSerializerOutputFormatter());
});
```

My object

```
public partial class Cartes
{
    public Cartes()
    {

    }

    public string CartNumero { get; set; }
    public int? CartConsId { get; set; }
    public int CartLotcaId { get; set; }
    public int CartTypcaId { get; set; }
    public string CartCrc { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CartDateAttribution { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CartDateClotureCarte { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CartDateSaisie { get; set; }
}
```

It's Work !

But when I add an ICollection property to Cartes the return is always in JSON !

```
public virtual ICollection<UtilisationsCriteres> UtilisationsCriteres { get; set; }
```

UtilisationsCriteres class :

```
public partial class UtilisationsCriteres
{
    public int UtcriConsId { get; set; }
    public int UtcriCrsupId { get; set; }
    public string UtcriValeur { get; set; }
    public int UtcriPartclieId { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcriDateInsert { get; set; }
    public DateTime UtcriDateUpdate { get; set; }
    public string UtcriUserUpdate { get; set; }
}
```

The return type of the controller is IActionResult.

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that (weird) behaviour. The collection can be null (or empty) and the content changes from `application/xml` to `application/json`.

XML serializator seems to be lost when using an interface instead of a concrete type. Maybe you should create a new issue on https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues.

The workaround is to use concrete classes. Changing `ICollection<UtilisationsCriteres>` to `System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<UtilisationsCriteres>` or `List<UtilisationsCriteres>` seems to work.

Comment: Thanks it's work ! 
I may be adding a issue on github ;)